# What does this notation mean in a many-body quantum system?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, notation, many-body, second-quantization

I'm studying the Many-body quantum system with the textbook [Many-Body Quantum Theory in Condensed Matter Physics](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Many-Body-Quantum-Theory-Condensed-Physics/dp/0198566336) written by Henrik Bruus and Karsten Flensberg, and right now I'm feeling hard to understand the context.

The problem is this. To describe the First Quantization of N-single particle system (The section 1.2.3 from the textbook), the author uses this notation:

local one particle operator : $T(\textbf{r}_j,\nabla_{\textbf{r}_j})$

$$ T_j=\sum_{\nu_a,\nu_b}^{} T_{\nu_b,\nu_a} \vert \psi_{\nu_b} (\textbf{r}_j) \rangle \langle \psi_{\nu_a}(\textbf{r}_j) \vert \quad ,$$
where
$$\quad T_{\nu_b,\nu_a}=\int d \textbf{r}_j \psi^*_{\nu_b}(\textbf{r}_j) T(\textbf{r}_j,\nabla_{\textbf{r}_j}) \psi^*_{\nu_a}(\textbf{r}_j)$$
and

\begin{equation*}
T_{\mathrm{tot}}=\sum_{j=1}^{N} T_j \quad .
\end{equation*}

Where I stuck is:

\begin{equation*}
T_{\mathrm{tot}}\psi(\textbf{r}_1,\textbf{r}_2,...,\textbf{r}_N)=\sum_{j=1}^{N}\sum_{\nu_a,\nu_b}T_{\nu_b,\nu_a}\delta_{\nu_a,\nu_{n_j}}\vert\psi_{\nu_{n1}}(\textbf{r}_1)\rangle...\vert\psi_{\nu_{b}}(\textbf{r}_j)\rangle...\vert\psi_{\nu_{n_N}}(\textbf{r}_N)\rangle
\end{equation*}

The lower indices $\nu_{n_i}$. What is this index mean? For example, if the index is $\nu_i$, it means that the wavefunction indicates ith identical particle in the quantum state $\nu$. Can anybody help me to understand?

Comment: Could these $\nu_i$ be placeholders for all quantum numbers/degrees of freedom? For example, it could just be the spin of the particle.

Comment: @JulianDeV Throughout the book, $\nu$ was used to notate all quantum numbers such as spin, wave propagate coordinate or if the state indicates the electron in hydrogen orbital then it means the orbital quantum numbers (n,l,m).

Comment: What edition/version do you have? My book has a different LHS. In the August, 2002 edition (online version) it reads: $T_\mathrm{tot}|\psi_{\nu_{n_1}}(r_1)\rangle \ldots$; in any case, IMHO the notation is really awful.

Comment: @TobiasFünke I don't know its exact edition but according to the preface section, It might be the 2003 edition.

Comment: @SoraS, if that's true then I think it's the same here. It might just be used as a discrete label over the quantum numbers to differentiate with the wavefunction's continuous dependence on the position.

Comment: @SoraS no big deal.  Many macros and definitions are not supported by [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/550071)